# Distributed Locust testing gets CPU to 100% while other CPU's are almost idle

Tags: distributed, locust

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I am running locust to stress load one of our system and am running it distributed on my local machine. One master, four workers, spawning 10 users. (This is the minimal testing, I will ramp up heavily as soon as I can figure out the issue).

As soon as I go on the webUI and start the test, two of my cores ramp up to 100% immediately, while the others remain idle throughout the test.  Any ideas on why the cores jump to 100% immediately and stay there while the other cores are almost idle?  They are all performing the same exact task.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks

I have tried using more or less workers, but the situation remains where one or more Cores go immediately to 100% regardless of the load or the spawning.

Comment: Check your logs. Something may be wrong. Since Locust is Python, it's limited by the GIL to 1 core per Python process, such as one instance of Locust. Not using your other CPU cores is expected. But any number of things could be causing the 100% CPU usage. A Python library you're using, Locust unable to reach the host you're targeting, etc. Your logs should help you see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. Something may be wrong. Since Locust is Python, it's limited by the GIL to 1 core per Python process, such as one instance of Locust. Not using your other CPU cores is expected. But any number of things could be causing the 100% CPU usage. A Python library you're using, Locust unable to reach the host you're targeting, etc. Your logs should help you see what's wrong.